# Regression Model Problems

Tags: tensorflow, keras

What is wrong with this model? I am new to learning about this stuff. Did I compile the model incorrectly or is it the structure itself?

Here's what the code looked like:
Y-set was defined as a list of floats [54.7, 52.5, 51.4, 51.5, 50.5] and so was x [0, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3.5]
Here's the code and the results for the training:

```
model = Sequential([
Dense(units = 1, input_shape = [1]),
Dense(units = 60, activation = 'relu'),
Dense(units = 1)])
model.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['mae'])
model.fit(x_set, y_set, epochs = 10)
```

This was the output it gave me:

```
        Epoch 1/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 1519.2493 - mae: 37.8005
        Epoch 2/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 577948.8750 - mae: 674.4330
        Epoch 3/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 159614431746567700480.0000 - 
        mae: 11284396032.0000
        Epoch 4/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: inf - mae: inf
        Epoch 5/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: nan - mae: nan
        Epoch 6/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: nan - mae: nan
        Epoch 7/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: nan - mae: nan
        Epoch 8/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: nan - mae: nan
        Epoch 9/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: nan - mae: nan
        Epoch 10/10
        1/1 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: nan - mae: nan
```

Obviously, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Just change a better optimizer o reduce the learning rate**:

For example:

```
x_set=np.array([0, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3.5])
y_set=np.array([54.7, 52.5, 51.4, 51.5, 50.5])

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(units = 1, input_shape = [1]),
    layers.Dense(units = 60, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Dense(units = 1)])
model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001), loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['mae'])
model.fit(x_set, y_set, epochs = 10)
```

Another thing you can do is to normalize your "x_set" and "y_set". This is optional but in many cases is very helpful. Remember to apply sigmoid in you output if your have normalized your "y_set" to 0-1.